# Mysqli prepare statement breaks image insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a sql statement that worked fine until I attempted to change it to a sql prepared statement.

Here is the old insert:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO items (seller, post_date, expiration_date, image, description, name, category, startBid, buyPrice, minPrice, sold) VALUES ('$id_user', NOW(), '$postDate', '$image', '$description', '$itemName', 0, '$startBid', '$buyNow', '$reservation', 0)";
$db->send_sql($sql);
```

And I attempt to make it prepared here:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO items (seller, post_date, expiration_date, image, description, name, category, startBid, buyPrice, minPrice, sold) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0)";
$stmt->bind_param("isbssiddd", $id_user, $postDate, $image, $description, $itemName, $itemCategory, $startBid, $buyNow, $reservation);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Both statements execute but they result in different image values in the database. The image value of the first statement is what I expected and can retrieved/shown. The image put in with the prepared statement shows stuff put in the database but does not show up as a valid image. The image field is a longblob. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How are you assigning `$image`? Also, there's plenty of comments on the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) manual page about extra steps involved in handling blobs

Comment: It was an issue with how I was setting $image. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue. This is how I was getting my $image:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['inputPic']['tmp_name']))
{
    if ($_FILES['inputPic']['type'] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['inputPic']['type'] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['inputPic']['type'] == "image/png")
    {
        if ($content = file_get_contents($_FILES['inputPic']['tmp_name']))
        {
            $image = addslashes($content);
        }
    }
}
```

I needed the addslashes function in the old mysql statement but not when it is prepared now. Making it `$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['inputPic']['tmp_name'])` resolved the issue